# How to get the value from the lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

how to get the value from the lambda function? I import the function in the program between different modules. This is just a test code representing the problem I need to solve (I am in the process of learning Python)

First module:

```
def get_test1(self):
    a = 5
    b = 7
    print(a*b)
    return a*b
```

Second module:

```
from GUI.module.gallery import Gallery

class GetHelp:

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def get_open_link(self):
        a = lambda: Gallery(self.root).get_test1()
        print(a)
        return a
GetHelp().get_open_link()
```

Currently I get the object `<function GetHelp.get_open_link.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f186f81be20>`.

Comment: Same way you get the value from a function defined with `def`: you have to *call* the function.

Comment: See [How to Use Python Lambda Functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/).

Comment: There's nothing special about a function defined by a lambda expression; it has the same type as something defined by a `def` statement. There are just times when it is *convenient* to define a function with an expression rather than a statement.

Comment: Why do you even use lambda? It should be `a = Gallery(self.root).get_test1()`

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a reference to a function object *produced* by the lambda expression. So, you could execute `a` as you do any function: `a()`.

Comment: `a` is a reference to a `function` object *produced* by the lambda expression.